# How do i deserialize object lists with-in curly brace?

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently having an issue trying to use C# Newtonsoft-Json to grab Json Objects

## Error Report

```
DummyClass
Data
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TicketDatum]]
System.String
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TicketDatum]
Run-time exception (line 77): Error converting value 1 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TicketDatum]'. Path 'data.ticket.budgetcost', line 1, position 33.

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TicketDatum].]
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
```

Tried using a Data-contract for specific objects

Here's the link to the code using [dotNET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBzRX4) which you can compile / run Online

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "ticket":{  
         "budgetcost":1,
         "id":151002,
         "icon":"icon2",
         "itemlevel":0,
         "name":"ticket",
         "sellable":"true",
         "override":{  
            "price":{  
               "quantity":1,
               "type":"gold"
            }
         },
         "stackable":"true",
         "stacksize":5000
      },
      "ticket2":{  
         "budgetcost":1,
         "id":151003,
         "icon":"icon2",
         "itemlevel":0,
         "name":"ticket2",
         "sellable":"true",
         "override":{  
            "price":{  
               "quantity":1,
               "type":"gold"
            }
         },
         "stackable":"true",
         "stacksize":11111
      }
   }
}
```

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        settings.ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver();
        
        var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DummyClass>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo: {" + foo.Data.Ticket.Count() + " }");
        
        foreach(var item in foo.Data.Ticket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
        }
```

```
 internal class DictionaryAsArrayResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(objectType);
            if (objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IDictionary) ||
                i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)))
                return CreateISerializableContract(objectType);

            return base.CreateContract(objectType);
        }
    }
```

It should be writing to console the Dictionary Keys and the Values should be the list of class objects

Comment: Where is the declaration of DummyClass? Maybe on that external link? It should be here too.

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eK5OPj)

Updated DummyClass to

```
 public class DummyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IDictionary<string, TicketDatum> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought maybe I had to create separate class for the property member. I definitely wouldn't of thought about this, seemed complex

Comment: @Proxicide And you don't really need any custom `ContractResolver` for this though.

Comment: @Proxicide Yep, that happens. BTW, for your information Json.NET actually supports [`Dictionary` serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) out of the box.

Comment: **every** JSON object is a key-value list with a unique key (property name) and that is also called a Dictionary ;o)

Answer (score 0):

your json is malformed,  it's not representing a dictionary of string , list
the below is.

a quick tip: sometimes it's easy to see these errors when you create an object, serialize it and try to deserialize it immediately ( or in this case look at the string it produces and compare it to what you're trying to read.

below is the correct structure ( as a string ) for your object hierarchy

```
{
  "data": {
    "Ticket": {
      "key1": [
        {
          "budgetcost": 1,
          "icon": "icn1",
          "id": 1,
          "itemlevel": 1,
          "name": "name1",
          "override": {
            "price": {
              "quantity": 1,
              "type": "ptypq1"
            }
          },
          "sellable": "yes1",
          "stackable": "yes1",
          "stacksize": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```